# casperjs function to variable to use in script url.toLowerCase error

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, phantomjs, casperjs

Okay i am going to run a script similar to this one :

```
casper.thenOpen(url2, function(){
this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
    'username': 'test',
    'password': 'test' },
true);
});
```

Basically i want to know how can i change this function into the url2 variable every time i try it my self i get url.toLowerCase error.

```
 this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
```

that code above is what i want to convert to var url2 variable

I have tried it like below but i get url.toLowerCase error

```
var url2 = this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
```

How can i use this as a variable correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? [`this.getCurrentUrl()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getcurrenturl)  works only on an opened page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try :

```
var url2 = this.getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: yes i have tried it this way but i get url.lowerCaseText error

Comment: bt@bt:~$ sudo casperjs 123.js https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/index.do?s_cid=con_FURL_btwifi TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase()') /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/utils.js:112 in cleanUrl /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1405 in open /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1832 in _step /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep

Comment: Are you under a casper.then(function() {}); ?

Comment: Brice Favre ill edit my post and show you the full code i am trying to achive a login after it has followed th url

Comment: theres is the new code above i no longer have errors but i am no nearer to achiving the login process yet